# Limit of the product of functions equaling the product of the limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Suppose that $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuously differentiable on $(-1,1)$. We are asked to show that the product $fg$ is continuous, but $f$ is a function of $x$, and $g$ is a function of $y$. We know that both f,g are continuous, but $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on different domains. What changes from the proof of this, and the proof of $\lim\limits_{x \to a}(fg)(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a}(f(x))\lim\limits_{x \to a} (g(x)).$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are just symbols, all that matters is that they're both defined on $(-1,1)$.  So I don't think anything changes from the proof you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, not much changes. A sequence of points (x,y) will converge to a point, say (x0, y0) in the two-dimensional space if and only if each of x and y converge to x0 and y0 in their respective one dimensional spaces. So the two-dimensional result basically follows from the one-dimensional one in this case; in other words f(x)g(y) will converge to f(x0)g(y0).